# How to copy a cordova project from one pc to another?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a cordova project located in a pc. Its contents are as follows:-
1. assets folder
2. lib folder
3. META-INF folder
4. res folder
5. AndroidManifest.xml
6. classes.dex
7. resources.arsc
How can I copy this project and run this successfully into some other pc?

Comment: Not sure about your question. Because you say cordova project and dint mentioned about www and plugins folders at all?

Comment: The www folder is inside the assets folder and the plugins folder is inside the www folder.

Comment: You can copy the complete project as is to the new pc's filesystem. But you gotta have all the build settings installed in the new pc like nodejs, npm, cordova etc, Once the build settings are available, you can port and build the project seamlessly

Comment: I can create other projects in my pc. But this project is not building . Its showing the following error:-
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char:

Comment: Did you try removing and re-adding the platform again? Also are you trying to build android or windows platform?

Comment: Its android platform. I removed the android platform and then tried to re-add it. The cmd window displays that android platform already exists but there is no android folder in the project. I created a new project by the way.

Comment: Was you cordova rm platform android command successful? i doubt. Better you create a new project using cordova create command, try adding required plugins using cordova plugin add command and try building the project as i sense something got corrupted in your project

Comment: One last question. Where shall I copy the folders and files mentioned in the question. I mean in which directory of my newly created project?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use git on github (or bitbucket). Or I would create a new cordova project, copy the www folder of the project you want to duplicate in the www folder of the new project, add all the plugin you need with CLI, and then do in CLI 'add platform android' and 'build android'.

Comment: Do I have to consider the different versions of cordova also? I have the latest version of cordova and I dont know the version of cordova in which the app was created

Comment: @UtkarshChauhan Of course you gotta consider the cordova version as some of the plugins will work only with certain versions and above of cordova. But if the cordova version is not too old in the new pc, you are good to go.

Comment: Different version of cordova will likely give you trouble. You have to try and go step by step with whatever could go wrong. But you can also update your cordova to an older version to match the version of the project you want to duplicate. You also have to becareful with android SDK because different version of cordova will want to build with different android SDK version (so you'll need to have those android SDK version).

Comment: I have the latest version of cordova and I have to make the project in this version only. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Create a new cordova project, duplicate www folder in your new cordova project, get (from the web) the latest version of the plugin the project use. If the plugin are up to date you should be fine. If not you might have to do some fine tuning in those. If you use a custom plugin you might have to work on that one too.

Comment: Shall I add a new plugin from cordova plugin add command? Also where can I get the plugins used in the project.?

Comment: First question: Yes. Second question: have a look in the doc.

Comment: One last question. Where shall I copy the folders and files mentioned in the question. I mean in which directory of my new project?

Comment: You don t manipulate those, it will be recreated when you do the 'cordova build android' CLI in your new project.

Comment: @UtkarshChauhan First create project using "cordova create PROJECT_NAME" command. It will create www folder for you. Then you can overwrite WWW folder and config.xml with your old project's one. Then you can add required plugin using 'cordova plugin add PLUGIN_NAME" command.

Comment: Do I have to replace the www folder inside the assets folder of new project or the www folder inside the root folder of the project?

Comment: @UtkarshChauhan Do not edit anything inside platforms/android folder directly as it will be overwritten when you do android build. Always edit the root project.

Comment: OK.. Thank You. It seems my config.xml of the older project got corrupted.  I have to create it again.